# What happens on SetBinding() in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, binding

I have the following code, which is part of a work-around for binding null values to a `ComboBox`. (Let's assume I'm not supportive of changing this implementation).

```
    SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, _cachedBinding);
```

**The question is:** does this line of code lead to Source updating Target and vice-versa?

So if I have this property in the view model:

```
 string MyProperty
 {
     get { return _myProperty; }
     set 
     {
        myProperty = value;
        IsDirty = true;
     }
 }
```

then the setter will be called when I call `SetBinding`. That will be troublesome since in the setter I'm also managing the `IsDirty property to keep track of changes. I can code:

```
 string MyProperty
 {
     get { return _myProperty; }
     set 
     {  
        if (myProperty != value)
        {
           myProperty = value;
           IsDirty = true;
        }
     }
 }
```

but I feel that would be inelegant since I have a lot of properties out there.

**So my second question is** (assuming the answer to first question is yes), can I force Silverlight to not update Target or Source after `SetBinding()` (so they would update only when they are changed)?

How this workaraound works: http://surrealization.com/sample-code/fixing-combobox-selectedvalue-bug-with-expression-behaviors/. `_cachedBinding` thus contains the binding that was set before `MyProperty` became `null` and the binding disappeared (so it's the same binding that was there (not same as an object though, since it was created anew)).

Looking at the code once again, that might be even the same object, but it depends on how `GetBindingExpression` and `ParentBinding` work in .NET.

Here is the fully binded `Combobox` subclass:

```
public class ComboBoxFixedBinding : ComboBox
{
    #region Events

    private void ComboBoxEx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (SelectedValue == null)
        {
            if (_cachedBinding != null && GetExistingBinding() == null)
            {
                SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, _cachedBinding);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CacheExistingBinding();
        }
    }

    private void CacheExistingBinding()
    {
        Binding binding = GetExistingBinding();

        if (binding != null)
        {
            _cachedBinding = binding;
        }
    }

    private Binding GetExistingBinding()
    {
        BindingExpression bindingExpr = this.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
        if (bindingExpr == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return bindingExpr.ParentBinding;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    public ComboBoxFixedBinding()
    {
        SelectionChanged += ComboBoxEx_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private Binding _cachedBinding;
}
```

Comment: We have to know what `_cachedBinding` contains in order to answer the question.